# POST/PUT/DELETE request fails for ReactJs, Express, and MongoDB application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've created a backend using node/express and mongodb. I have a mongodb cloud instance running via mLab. For creating CRUD requests to db, I'm using `mongoose` package. The proxies are set correctly, my server is running on port:5000 and reactjs frontend app on port:3000 and all the data is flowing correctly in the system.

This is my schema - **models/Campaign.js**:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const { Schema } = mongoose;

const campaignSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  createdOn: Number,
  price: Number,
});

mongoose.model("campaigns", campaignSchema);
```

These are my routes - **routes/CampaignRoutes.js**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Campaign = mongoose.model("campaigns");

module.exports = app => {
  app.get(`/api/campaigns`, async (req, res) => {
    let campaigns = await Campaign.find();
    return res.status(200).send(campaigns);
  });

  ...

  app.put(`/api/campaign/:id`, async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;

    let campaign = await Campaign.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body);

    return res.status(202).send({
      error: false,
      campaign
    });
  });

  app.delete(`/api/campaign/:id`, async (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;

    let campaign = await Campaign.findByIdAndDelete(id);

    return res.status(202).send({
      error: false,
      campaign
    });
  });
};
```

From my frontend, Im calling these endpoints as below - **api.js**:

GET request works absolutely fine:

```
export const fetchCampaigns = async () => {
  const url = `api/campaigns`;

  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);

    return await response.json();
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }

  return null;
};
```

**However, PUT/DELETE requests fails with 404:**

```
export const updateCampaign = async (id, data) => {
  const url = `api/campaign/${id}`;

  try {
    const response = await fetch(url, {
      method: "PUT",
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    });

    let results = await response.json();

    return results;
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }

  return null;
};
```

Basically any request like `api/xyx/:id` fails!
On postman, the same PUT/DELETE requests works just fine.

I can't for the life, figure out why i'm getting 404s. Please help.

Comment: Try printing your `url` in console before making the PUT/DELETE request. Is it looking good?

Comment: @AjayDabas ya i checked it and it looks fine: `http://localhost:3000/api/campaign/5deb6596e7179a3015b03a68`

If i put the same request in postman, it works just fine. One thing to note is that the port here is `3000` but my server is at `5000`. I believe proxy should be able to resolve this as the GET request works fine.

Comment: Do you have this code open-sourced on GitHub or somewhere? I want to replicate the error and see it for myself.

Comment: let me push it and get back to you.

Comment: do you have a .env @saran3h

Comment: @AjayDabas i've pushed it to github: `https://github.com/saranshbansal/sbansal-campaign-manager`. Let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: Adding `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"` in `package.json` fixes your issue. So, your proxy was not correctly configured.

Comment: @AjayDabas brilliant! I remember adding a proxy in package.json but then removed it later as nothing happened. Glad it worked.

I don't understand though how data is successfully being fetched even without the above fix.

Comment: Yea that's bugging me too. With just `setupProxy.js`, some routes were working correctly but others were not. Just go with proxy in package.json I guess.